# How to compile scala library to latest scala version

Tags: scala, sbt

I want to use this library https://github.com/prismicio/scala-kit.
My project's scala version is `2.13.1`. When I add this library as dependency:

`val prismic = "io.prismic" % "scala-kit_2.11" % "1.3.1"`

I get `NoClassDefinitionFound` error at runtime. I guess it's due to version conflict. So how do I publish this library so it works for scala version `2.13.1`?

Answer (score 3):

Scala has no binary compatibility across major versions (i.e. 2.11.1 and 2.13.1). Either downgrade to 2.11.1 (or 2.12.2 if you switch to the latest version of the library) `scalaVersion := "2.11.1"` or compile the library to 2.13.1 yourself.

Comment: Maybe you can update the version in the sbt build and it will just work. The commit updating to 2.12 was trivial. Or, consider the project moribund and consider other options.

Comment: I tried updating Build.sbt scala version but it gave a ton of  compile errors.

Comment: Can you please extend your answer for how to make a custom maven repository, like where does the publish artifacts go and how can I serve that folder as resolver

Answer (score 0):

What you should use is

```
val prismic = "io.prismic" %% "scala-kit" % "1.3.1"
```

which adds the correct suffix automatically, and you can't forget to change it when changing the Scala version. But if you look at https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.prismic/scala-kit, you'll see there is no version for 2.13 at all, but there are versions for 2.12. So if you want to change your Scala version, use 2.12.10 (the latest 2.12).